# Pasting diagram for Kan extensions in xypic?

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

Is there some way to typeset the diagram below in `xypic`? I find it impossible to work out the methodology behind `\compositemap` and would really appreciate some help.

[image]

Here's what I produced:

```
\xymatrix{\mathsf{C}\ar[rr]^{F}\ar[dr]_{K} & \ar@{}[d]|{\Downarrow \eta} & \mathsf{E}\\
& \mathsf{D}\urtwocell_{G}{\exists!}
```

which compiles to:

[image]

I don't know how to get the label in the middle of the top curved arrow, nor how to really properly space `\Downarrow \eta`. I think `compositemap` takes care of all this automatically...

Answer (score 1):

You should abandon `xypic` and turn to more user-friendly ways to picture commutative diagrams, like `pgf`/`tikz`-based ones. Not to mention that you can cheat a bit and make `tikz` commutative diagrams look like they were drawn using `xy`!

Here's my suggestion as a MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, column sep=2cm]
% drawing 0- and 1-celss
\mathsf{C}  \ar[dr, "K"', ""{name=K}]
            \ar[rr, "F", ""{name=F, below, near start, bend right}]&&
\mathsf{E}\\
& \mathsf{D}    \ar[ur, bend left, "\text{Lan}_KF", ""{name=Lan, below}]
                \ar[ur, bend right, "G"', ""{name=G}]
%
% drawing 2-cells  
\arrow[Rightarrow, "\exists!", from=Lan, to=G]
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=F, to=K, "\eta"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) the documentation of `tikz-cd`.